# Using Bitcoin for Travel Purchases

Tags: travel

[BitCoin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin) is (arguably) the world's best chance thus far at a virtual currency (although it's very unstable).  Even though it's a high risk, it is able to be converted to regular dollars, and some shops and online sites accept payment in Bitcoins.

Is there a way to convert BitCoins to regular currency online, or is there a world-wide travel website that you can use BitCoins to purchase flights, tickets, etc with?

Comment: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade#Travel_.2F_Tourism_.2F_Leisure

Answer (score 7):

+1 for fun question. Places where you can [sell bitcoins](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Selling_bitcoins) are a plenty. You are a bit late though since the exchange rate was much higher earlier this year. Purchasing stuff with bitcoins isn't that widespread. [bitcoin.travel](http://bitcoin.travel/) lists about 10 travel releated places in the entire world that accepts bitcoins. bitcoin.it also has a [list of travelling related vendors accepting bitcoins](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade#Travel_.2F_Tourism_.2F_Leisure). All this may change quickly in either direction so watch these sites for updates.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert Bitcoins to a number of currencies and have them wired to a local bank from [many online exchanges](http://bitcoincharts.com/markets/).

Moreover, [OKPAY](https://www.okpay.com/en/index.html) is to soon accept Bitcoins, which will allow you to conveniently pay with your coins pretty much anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Localbitcoins.com for hand to hand exchages